# Noobie to Paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm the web developer for a small regional nonprofit, and we are trying to
find a way to handle registration fees (and donations) on our website. Registration form is already constructed, but not yet public:  user goes to
that form, enters their ID, contact info, and registration/donation details.  Form calculates (via javascript) the total fee, and sends the information to a PHP script which displays a printable confirmation.  If user accepts, they are sent a copy, and the user is entered in our registration database.  This is the point at which user would be transferred to PayPal to pay a single fixed amount in USD, either with their own PP account or with a credit card.

Our financial staff has set up an account with PayPal.  Have been spending several hours looking through the PayPal API documentation.  There seem to be many choices. Would like to find something that is easy, not fancy, and can be set up quickly.  We need to get a workable solution out soon: conference is in less than seven weeks.  What would you recommend?

NEW:  Made some progress, by reading the steps to create an "Express Checkout" (developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/).  It gave a script  to paste in to get a PayPal button to occur on the PHP.  I needed to log into our PayPal account to create an App, which included a "Client ID".  Wiith that I was able to specify the fee in from the registration form payment:

```
     { total: <?echo $_POST["Fee"] ?>, currency: "USD" }
```

and the user was presented with a choice to pay the given amt.

SECOND UPDATE:  Here's the script I wrote, copying from

< https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/ >

where the entries in the client: option were found by logging in as the account owner, creating apps in both the sandbox and live environments.
A paypal button shows up on our web page, and pushing it does direct the user to a paypal checkout box.  But:

1) the checkout box displays the email address of the account owner - why ??

2) box appears to complete a transaction, either with an existing paypal account (I tried it with my personal PayPal account) or with a credit card; BUT

- no record of the transaction shows up on the Dashboard
- neither the credit card nor the paypal account of the customer shows a charge, even using the client ID from the live environment app.

any clues as to what's going on would be appreciated -

```
       <div id="paypal-button"></div>
       <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
       <script>
           paypal.Button.render({
               env: 'production', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment
       //        env: 'sandbox', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment
          client: {
     //           sandbox:    'AbdRi30wSEQwWz2PNHoj0BzvkfsJ-wv9AAxXwWRlYa3vm0B2f8aX2MIjyNErENmFqihq1afdpEcOgfcD',
                  production: 'ARgP9eaIwbgsU9LmTLpKJSDchHNNxD5u_ysEVhjp26dCu1g21MUrjb4lQepMsNixk1D35y_ec07dsRAS'
              },
               payment: function() {
                   var env    = this.props.env;
                   var client = this.props.client;
                   return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                       transactions: [
                           {
                               amount: { total: <?echo $Fees?>, currency: 'USD' }
                           }
                       ]
                   });
               },
                   // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
               commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow           
               onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        // Execute the payment here, when the buyer approves the            transaction
              }
        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
    </DIV>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside It is very easy to implement at least for me. I hope this helps. You will need to have access to that PayPal account created by your financial staff and log into it before you can work on the Donation API

Comment: Thank you, Joseph.  Will look at your reference.  For other potential noobies, I did make some progress on this; edited original post to show what I found.

Answer (score -2):

I know this wasn't your question but have a look at Stripe - it's much easier to integrate and lets you take payments for all debit/credit cards. PayPal is a lot more difficult to integrate in my opinion.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: Thank you, Chris.  We actually have an account with Stripe (and they charge less than PayPal), but didn't have any luck on my first try at integration.  Will take another look at the checkout page.

Comment: Stripe requires that the page calling checkout be addressed with https.  (Our SSL is out of date; sysadmins said they could fix this.)  But using https to call the page on which I've included the checkout.js form, even in test mode, and even telling the browser to override the security, just gives a 404 - Not Found.

Comment: Can you share a URL?

Comment: The registration site is at sections.maa.org/maa2017/regform.html.  Filling in the form will take you to the page with the Stripe and Paypal scripts.